# How to keep check color on Coordinates for macro?

Tags: c#, macros

i want keep check color on Coordinates direct after press start button and stop when i pressed on stop button it's will be like macro for me but when i pressed on start button nothing happens it's not pressed S button from keyboard at all i need to to keep pressed S button while condition true and here my code

```
using Eyedropper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace macro
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Bitmap m_ScreenImage;

        private void btnstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (m_ScreenImage.GetPixel(1002, 109).ToString() == "Color [A=255, R=55, G=114, B=173]")
            {

                m_ScreenImage = Utility.CaptureScreen();
                SendKeys.Send("s");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question so that readers can have an idea of what you're talking about. Reading the question, I don't understand what "check color", "coordinates", the "start", "stop" and "S" buttons are, and how "macros" fit into it. From your code, it seems like you are writing a Windows Forms desktop app (you should tag it that way). Other than that, I'm at a bit of a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but I'll give you some pointers

This is a one way trip to a huge memory leak and running out of *GDI* resources

```
m_ScreenImage = Utility.CaptureScreen();
```

You should dispose your `Bitmaps`

```
m_ScreenImage?.Dispose();
m_ScreenImage = Utility.CaptureScreen();
```

This is a very long winded approach to checking a pixel color.

```
m_ScreenImage.GetPixel(1002, 109).ToString() == "Color [A=255, R=55, G=114, B=173]"
```

It's better to store the color you want and just check it against the color returned from `GetPixel`

[FromArgb(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Color_FromArgb_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

> Creates a Color structure from the four ARGB component (alpha, red,
>   green, and blue) values. Although this method allows a 32-bit value to
>   be passed for each component, the value of each component is limited
>   to 8 bits.

```
public Color targetColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 55, 114, 173);

...

while (m_ScreenImage.GetPixel(1002, 109) == targetColor)
{ ... }
```

As for why your send key is not working, well, I'm not sure. However, my feeling is you are just stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: thanks for reply
yes i'm stuck in an endless loop this loop will not stop until press button stop will be stop and how about send key?